# using scrollTo plugin and click and hold functionality to add navigation elements to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

You can view the site at [www.highdwellercreative.com/colife](http://www.highdwellercreative.com/colife). This site is based around the concept the the city will grow as the company grows and we wanted a different feeling then scrolling with the scroll bars provided. I have been working on a keypad style of navigation that consists of four directional arrows (up, down, left, right).

I am currently using setInterval() function to loop the scrollTo Plugin on mousedown() and the clearInterval() function to end the loop on mouseup().

I have also set the interval to repeat at 1 millisecond to achieve smooth scrolling. I have included the code that makes what I have accomplished so far work but it is still a bit rough, especially in Firefox 4. So far this does work in all browsers, including IE, but it could stand to be smoother and I am at a loss of how to accomplish this. Also if you click on one of the navigation buttons and immediately do a right click on it, the page gets stuck scrolling in that direction. Any help on how to improve this would be greatly appreciated.

```
var rightId;

$('span#right').mousedown(function() {

    rightId = setInterval(function(){$.scrollTo('+=5px', {axis:'x'})}, 1);

}).mouseup(function() {

    clearInterval(rightId);

});

var leftId;

$('span#left').mousedown(function() {

    leftId = setInterval(function(){$.scrollTo('-=5px', {axis:'x'})}, 1);

}).mouseup(function() {

    clearInterval(leftId);

});

var upId;

$('span#up').mousedown(function() {

    upId = setInterval(function(){$.scrollTo('-=5px', {axis:'y'})}, 1);

}).mouseup(function() {

    clearInterval(upId);

});

var downId;

$('span#down').mousedown(function() {

    downId = setInterval(function(){$.scrollTo('+=5px', {axis:'y'})}, 1);

}).mouseup(function() {

    clearInterval(downId);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly put these all into a single function:

```
function moveAround(elem,dir,moveAxis) {
  var moving;
  $(elem).mousedown(function() {
    moving = setInterval(function(){$.scrollTo(dir+'=5px', {axis:moveAxis})}, 1);
  }).mouseup(function() {
    clearInterval(moving);
  });
}
moveAround('span#left','-','x');
moveAround('span#right','+','x');
moveAround('span#up','-','y');
moveAround('span#down','+','y');
```

Just in terms of functionality, you may want to make a double click move you 500px or something. Just so people can get around the city faster. :)

An alternative way to do this would be to use .animate, with a callback function that called the same function (as long as the mousedown was still active).